# sorting when class object is used as a key to map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have created a class with student details(name and id) and I want to use the object of that class as key value to map. 
I have some questions

1. I am getting error while compiling this code. Kindly tell me the solution for this?
2. As map is ordered, here I have object as a key value and it has both string and number based on what the key value will get sorted?
3. I have used

   ```
   cout<<(*ii).first<<'\t'<<(*ii).second<<endl;
   ```

   to print the value. Is that the correct way to print the value of class object

   ```
   ( (*ii).first)?
   ```

Kindly find my code below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map.h>
#include<utility>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    private:
    char name[10];
    int id_no;
    public:
    A(char *myname,int no):id_no(no)
    {
        strcpy(name,myname);
    }
    void output()
    {
        cout<<name<<'\t'<<id_no<<endl;
    }
};     

int main()
{
    map<A,int> e;
    A a("abc",10);
    A b("xyz",1);

    e.insert(pair<A,int>(a,123));
    e.insert(pair<A,int>(b,345));


    for(map<A,int>::iterator ii = e.begin(); ii!= e.end(); ii++)
    {
        cout<<(*ii).first<<"rank is"<<(*ii).second<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. > I am getting error while compiling this code.

   `std::map` uses `std::less`(default) to compare keys. `std::less` uses `operator<` to compare passed objects. So, you should overload `operator<` for your class:

   ```
   bool operator< (const A& a)
   {
       // compare
   }
   ```
2. > Based on what the key value will get sorted?

   It will depends on your overloaded `operator<`.
3. > Is that the correct way to print the value of class object?

   The more general way: you should overload `operator<<` for `std::ostream` object and your class object:

   ```
   friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const A& a)
   {
       stream << a.name << '\t' << a.id_no << std::endl;
       return stream;
   }
   ```

   Only then you can print it like this:

   ```
   cout << ii -> first << "rank is" << ii -> second << endl;
   ```

   Without it you should use your `output` function:

   ```
   ii -> first.output();
   cout << "rank is" << ii -> second << endl;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<utility>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    string name; // there is no reason not using string here
    int id_no;
public:
    A(char *myname, int no) : name(myname), id_no(no)
    {
    }

    void output()
    {
        cout<<name<<'\t'<<id_no<<endl;
    }

    const string & getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }

    bool operator<(const A &right) const // A must be comparable to be used as keys
    {
        return name < right.name;
    }
};     

int main()
{
    map<A,int> e;
    A a("abc",10);
    A b("xyz",1);

    e.insert(pair<A,int>(a,123));
    e.insert(pair<A,int>(b,345));

    for(map<A,int>::iterator ii = e.begin(); ii!= e.end(); ii++)
    {
        cout<<(*ii).first.getName() << " rank is " <<(*ii).second<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```